# How to access bitcoins with my private key but no passphrase?

Tags: bitcoin-core, paper-wallet, passphrase, private-key-import

I  utilized a website, [bitcoinpaperwallet.com](https://bitcoinpaperwallet.com/), to randomly generate a Private and Public key pair for Bitcoins storage.

This new Public address is now available for anyone to send bitcoins into.
If I want to make transactions with those newly acquired bitcoins I have to open my bitcoin wallet (it my case it would be bitcoin-qt) and introduce this new private key from the console window to be able to access the funds.
Instructions for such operation apparently is as follow:

**`importprivkey 5KsomeCaracteresAndNumers765whichIsTheactuaLPrivKey  NameOfKey false`**

This does not work because the wallet require a PassPhrase. Here is the generated error:

**`Please enter the wallet passphrase with walletpassphrase first. (code -13)`**

bitcoinpaperwallet.com  did not issue any PassPhrase for my private-public key.

*THE QUESTION*: 
How do I enter my private key into bitcoin-qt to get access to the funds ?

Comment: The passphrase is for the bitcoin core wallet application not the keys and address you generated. See https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.17.0/rpc/wallet/walletpassphrase/

Comment: This should be a wallet passphrase that you previously set within Bitcoin Core.  It's only needed so that your newly imported key can be encrypted with the same passphrase and stored with your other keys.  If you have forgotten it, you can start over with a new wallet file.

Comment: By the way, if you actually want to be able to spend coins received on the address prior to importing it, you'll have to change the `false` to `true` (and wait for a rescan to complete, which may take hours).

Comment: re: @NateEldredge 's comment: rather than wait hours, if you know the blocks that include your relevant transactions, you could leave `importprivkey ... false` and then after that run `rescanblockchain ("start_height") ("stop_height")`. That would be much quicker, as there is no need to rescan everything if you know the relevant block heights.